# SSAS Standard Edition Tabular Model Process - Low Memory Error

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

This is the environment I work with:

1. Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition (64-bit)
2. One database engine instance with 3 databases
3. One Analysis Services instance with 4 databases (Tabular model, average size of each database 3.9 gb)
4. Database engine and ssas are on same server.
5. Server has 256gb ram; 80gb allocated to database engine, 60 gb allocated to etl tool.

I read, if SQL Server is Standard Edition, it will assign a limited memory (15gb) to analysis service database. Also I can not create a new partition for one table. I wanted to create multiple partitions for one table and refresh/process only partition which has hot data. But I couldn't do that.

So unfortunately, I have to full process for each tables. If there is an option to achieve this?

Here are my steps to process:

1. When I try to deploy ssas tabular model via Visual Studio, it throws "low memory" error. I have 10 tables in my tabular model, so I filtered table queries to "select top 10". After that I deployed the model successfully.
2. After first step, I edited and removed "top 10" part from each tables partition in SQL Server Management Studio.
3. I extracted full process script for each partitions, created a linked server between database and ssas instance.
4. I created cursor to process partition of 10 tables. But I got an error "low memory".

Here is an example of process a partition.

```
   DECLARE @MyScript NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"refresh":{"type":"full","objects":[{"database":"Dwh_Reports","table":"Fact Sales","partition":"Par_Fact_Sales"}]}}'

   EXEC (@MyScript) AT SSAS
```

To sum up, my questions;

- I have 4 databases on my ssas instance. That means, per instance uses 15gb memory and i have to allocate 60gb memory to ssas?
- My ssas instance configuration is default, I didn't change anything;

  ```
   Memory \ LowMemoryLimit       -> Value : 60
   Memory \ TotalMemoryLimit     -> Value : 80
   Memory \ VertiPaqMemoryLimit  -> Value : 60
   Memory \ VertiPaqPagingPolicy -> Value : 1
  ```

Do I have to change this configurations?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232833/ssas-model-refresh-not-enough-memory-to-complete-this-operation-error

Comment: Hi @Subbu, accepted answer is seperating sql and ssas. This is not an answer and unfortunately i can not do that. Also i've 256gm memory, when i take a look to task manager, msmdrv.exe uses 10gb~ ram.

Comment: Looking at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15, the 16 GB limit in Standard Edition for SSAS tabular is "per instance". I would assume this to be the per installation of SSAS (i.e., not per database). So, possibly, your model is bigger than Standard edition can handle. If you can, you can use a developer edition to test this.